# return concatenated input with an .empty and .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get a return value for the concatenation of first and last name.  I basically need to concatenate the input fields from a form to return a message if empty or return the first and last name if the user supplies this information into the fields.

`#message` is my div tag in the HTML.

It returns back the values but does not return back the message "Please enter your first and last name." if input boxes are null.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
 var getName = function() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName"),
    lastName = document.getElementById("lastName"),
    fullName;   

    if (firstName.value == "" && lastName.value == "" ) {
       fullName= $("#message").empty().append("Please enter your first and last name.");
    } else {
       fullName = firstName.value + " " + lastName.value;
    }
    return $("#message").empty().append(fullName);
 }
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#message").empty().append("Hello world");
 });




Here is the HTML for the form 

 <form name="contactform" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" placeholder= "First Name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder= "Last Name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder= "Email Address">
    <p>
    <h4> What is your sex? </h4>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
    Male
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">
    Female
    <p>
    <h4> What is your favorite type of music </h4>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="rock">
    I like Rock and Roll<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="funk">
    I like Funk
    <p>
      <textarea  name="comments" placeholder= "Additional Comments"></textarea>
      <input type="button"  name="submit" id="submit"  value="Get Name" onclick="getName();" />
  </form>
```

Comment: thanks I updated this.

Comment: Did you mean to have spaces after the `.empty()` functions?

Comment: What does your HTMl look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the "Please enter your first and last name." as a text value instead of trying to pass a jquery statement.

Look at this JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kW4b6/

I just changed this line:

```
fullName= $("#message").empty().append("Please enter your first and last name.");
```

To this:

```
fullName = "Please enter your first and last name.";
```